# Where is secret door that the old pirate at the Bluefin Club tells you about?

Tags: dragon-fantasy

The old pirate at the Bluefin club said go to his former hideout, at base of the volcano, and find the secret door. I went to the volcano, killed the dungeon boss, and opened all chest, but I couldn't find the secret door.

Where is the secret door?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [one of the developers](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?s=8af5392ceac768c06c252bca08ef1d48&p=1892133&postcount=97):

> **The secret entrance is actually the entrance to the volcano** - Ogden is supposed to say something about finding it when you enter the volcano the first time... wonder if that's not working right or something? Anyway, once you beat the boss of the Volcano, it's just time to head down to Crescent Cove and get to the mines. I'll tweak the script a little bit in the next big update to make sure this is more clear.

So you've already found the "secret" door.